# Is the Cake Pattern missing from Haskell? Why and when would I need to use the Cake Pattern in Haskell?

Tags: scala, haskell, cake-pattern

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947176/can-scalas-cake-pattern-be-implemented-in-haskell) and [this thread on Reddit](https://m.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1629ld/olegs_go_at_reproducing_scalas_cake_pattern/) inspired me to ask:

Why don't people in the Haskell community seem to be missing Scala's Cake Pattern? Why is the lack (or cumbersomeness) of a Cake Pattern in Haskell not a such a big issue?

The [Cake Pattern](http://events.inf.ed.ac.uk/Milner2012/M_Odersky-html5-mp4.html) is meant to help with large (scalable) systems/programs. Is it possible that systems created with Scala tend to be much larger than systems created with Haskell? This in turn might explain why the Cake Pattern is so important in the Scala world and its lack is not such a big issue in the Haskell world?

Comment: Just a few guesses: it models Objects (i.e. OO objects) and Haskell does not have Objects. Probably most Haskellers would balk at the thought of trying to hack Objects into their Haskell code... Haskell and Scala have vastly different type systems, I wouldn't expect design patterns applicable to Scala to be applicable to Haskell in general. Furthermore, Scala has much better support for runtime reflection, so combining the Cake pattern and reflection gets you the power of the model for no syntactic inconvenience. In Haskell you won't even get a first class object out of it.

Comment: Perhaps the Cake Pattern isn't as valuable to those with access to a good [reader monad](http://blog.originate.com/blog/2013/10/21/reader-monad-for-dependency-injection/).

Comment: maybe you should first add what a *cake pattern* is - tbh: this is the first time I heard of it and I am to lazy to search for it myself ^^

Comment: Is it an exaggeration to say that Haskell programmers in general don't care very much about so-called "patterns"?

Comment: The Cake Pattern is _but one way_ in Scala to compose big modules out of smaller modules. There are lots of others; the Cake Pattern is not the most popular or even necessarily the best (it's not simple, for sure).
In Haskell we compose big things out of smaller things _all the time_, and the language also gives us lots of tools with which to do it. To solve the particular problem that the Cake Pattern is used for, the most commonly-used tool is probably monad transformers.

Comment: @Carsten the first link explains it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947176/can-scalas-cake-pattern-be-implemented-in-haskell

Comment: @jhegedus: Maybe it would help if you could describe the kind of problems that the cake pattern solves, instead of explaining the pattern itself. Then we could show how these problems are a) solved or b) not existent in Haskell.

Comment: I added a link to a talk that explains the Cake Pattern and why it is a good idea. @Carsten

Comment: @Bergi the link I added explains the purpose of Cake Pattern very well.

Comment: the cake pattern is a lie

Comment: @sclv what do u mean ?

Comment: this https://twitter.com/miguelinlas3/status/547660890821361664

Comment: @jhegedus I doubt very many people are going to watch a 40 minute video to understand some of the context of this question to decide if they want to answer it. I don't necessarily agree that this question ought to be closed as too broad, but if the cake pattern is so complicated that the core ideas can't be summarised in the question then it probably can't be well answered in this format either.

Comment: @Ben this question targets people who know already _both_ Scala and Haskell. The purpose of the question is not to teach Scala. The cake pattern is explained in detail in Odersky's Scala (intro) book, as well, but I think this video really well summarises why the cake pattern was invented/discovered and what problems ( i.e. Dependency injection) it tries to solve and how (the how part needs understanding of Scala).